# Phoenix : Having a JSON and HTML representation of the same resource

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm starting to use Phoenix outside of tutorials for a small use case. So far great, but I'm a bit taken aback by the following.

I have a resource "recording" that I want to access at /api/recordings in JSON and at /recording with a template and the result being HTML.

Ideally the Ecto representation would be unique, and even part of the controller would also be shared?

Right now I either have to have 2 resources recordingAPI and recordingHTML, or 2 controllers and 1 resources.

Any exemple out there? I keep finding one or the other, but not something with the :api pipe and the :browser pipe used for the same resource.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can utilize phoenix `accepts` plug and a combination of two different views/layouts

```
# router.ex
defmodule TestExWeb.Router do
  use TestExWeb, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", TestExWeb do
    pipe_through :browser

    get "/recording", PageController, :index
  end

  scope "/api", TestExWeb do
    pipe_through :api

    get "/recording", PageController, :index
  end
end
```

As you can see, `:browser` uses `:accepts ["html"]` while `:api` uses `:accepts ["json"]`. You can find this in the private struct of your `conn` and use it in the controller like this:

```
defmodule TestExWeb.PageController do
  use TestExWeb, :controller

  def index(%{private: %{phoenix_format: format}} = conn, _params) do
    data = "Hello World"

    render(conn, "index.#{format}", data: data)
  end
end
```

Now, you just need to tell phoenix how to render your json, html is already taken care of by `page.html.eex` in layouts, so add the following to your `page_view.ex`

```
defmodule TestExWeb.PageView do
  use TestExWeb, :view

  def render("index.json", %{data: data}) do
    %{
      data: data
    }
  end
end
```

Two drawbacks with this solution:

- You need this format snippet in every controller (Maybe you can circumvent this with a plug after you "sent" the response)
- You're using an internal variable of phoenix